# R: can chisq.test() take a table as an object?

Tags: r, chi-squared

The R-documentation at `?chisq.test()` says that x has to be

> a numeric vector or matrix. x and y can also both be factors

Yet on the internet you find examples of `chisq.test` being run on contingency tables, i.e. creating a table from a dataframe using

```
mytable <- table(df$a, df$b)
```

and then running `chisq.test` on

```
chisq.test(mytable)
```

Are the chi-square values and p values obtained this way valid?

Comment: `is.matrix(table(a,b))` returns `TRUE`. So, yep.

Comment: Wow, that's so elegant, thanks, @thelatemail ! I never realised that a table was a matrix!